# Snowpark Snowflake UDF input and return type error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowpark, I am trying to write a custom UDF but facing errors while passing input and return types.

Code

```
@udf
def new(df: PandasDataFrame[int, float, float]) -> PandasDataFrame[int, str]):
        // my code
        return df
```

Error

```
Invalid ReturnType or input types for udf : return type PandasDataFrameType(), input types PandasDataFrametype()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowpark Python UDFs are scalar functions; for each row passed to the UDF, the UDF returns a value, as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-introduction.html#what-is-a-python-udf).

If you use [Python UDF Batch API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-batch.html#python-udf-batch-api) you can return batches of results as [Pandas arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.array.html) or [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html), but that is the closest you can get as of now.